# Regarding selecting all the java files from project src folder

Tags: java, io

I have developed a application in which user select the particular folder and it counts all the java files in that folder plus the line of code individually in those files and show at console but in a java project there are so many packages and right now I have to navigate until a particular package , I want to modify the application in such a way that when user select the particular project, he will then further navigate to only src folder and from src folder all the packages containing java files line of code will be counted.

Please advise how to achieve that..below is my piece of code:

```
public class abc {


    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {      Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
             int totalLineCount = 0;
             File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                  @Override
                  public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                      if(name.endsWith(".java"))
                      return true;
                    else
                      return false;              
                  }
                }
   );
              for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                    int lineCount = 0;
                     try
                    { for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) ;
                          } catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {   result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;  
                                    }


                } }
              System.out.println("*****************************************");
              System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
              System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet())
            {   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>"+"\t"+result.size()); 
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>"+"\t"+ totalLineCount);

             }     

    }

}
```

the problem with my code is now when I start my application an dialog box get opened in which I have to browse till the complete package folder which finally contains the java files but now I want to modify the application in such a way so that when file diaolog box get opened , user will navigate to project src folder only and from then onwards all the packages inside the src folder need to be scanned and all the files line of code,please advise..

What I was thinking was...

- Given a File Object that represents a directory (we will call it Directory):
- Get all the Files in the Directory.
- For Each File in the Directory, (we will call it thisFile) do the following:
- If thisFile is a directory, start from the beginning use thisFile as the Directory
- Else, If thisFile is a .java file, count the lines of code
- Else, ignore thisFile

This gets a whole lot easier if you separate the main into methods.

Comment: folks please advise for this and advise what modifications I need to do in my above piece of code to achieve this

Comment: Whatever you thought above will work.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal but please tell me how to implement it in my above code

Comment: Hi Folks Please advise for this as I am stuck up with this problem

Comment: Doing modification into your logic, let me get it work

Comment: @RahulAgrawal sure Rahul Thanks a lot , please post the edit code with modifications thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code goes

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class abc {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    private static int totalLineCount = 0;
    private static int totalFileScannedCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

            List<File> files = getFileListing(directory);

            //print out all file names, in the the order of File.compareTo()
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("Directory: "+file);
                result = getFileLineCount(file);
                totalFileScannedCount +=  result.size();
            }


            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
            System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>" + "\t" + totalFileScannedCount);
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>" + "\t" + totalLineCount);

        }

    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getFileLineCount(File directory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                if (name.endsWith(".java")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                int lineCount = 0;
                try {
                    for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively walk a directory tree and return a List of all
     * Files found; the List is sorted using File.compareTo().
     *
     * @param aStartingDir is a valid directory, which can be read.
     */
    static public List<File> getFileListing(
            File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        validateDirectory(aStartingDir);
        List<File> result = getFileListingNoSort(aStartingDir);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    // PRIVATE //
    static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(
            File aStartingDir) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] filesAndDirs = aStartingDir.listFiles();
        List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
        for (File file : filesDirs) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file); 
            }
            if (!file.isFile()) {
                //must be a directory
                //recursive call!
                List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
                result.addAll(deeperList);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Directory is valid if it exists, does not represent a file, and can be read.
     */
    static private void validateDirectory(
            File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (aDirectory == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory should not be null.");
        }
        if (!aDirectory.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Directory does not exist: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Is not a directory: " + aDirectory);
        }
        if (!aDirectory.canRead()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory cannot be read: " + aDirectory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agarwal thanks a lot but still there are few bugs in the application that is if in java project there are 3 packages and each package having 2 files each then in the result on console it shows file name followed by loc of only the latest package only

Comment: please advise how it can show all the files along with line numbers in each package just by selection the project name itself from the jfile chooser itself, it is rite now showing this for only the latest package only, thanks in advance

Comment: but overall  total sum of lines of code for the whole project is perfect , please advise

Comment: Can you give an example to understand the problem, which you are having now

Comment: I have edited the post explaining the problem, kindly refer to it

Comment: is that if in java project named TESTRESULT there are 3 packages and each package having 2 files each then in the result on console it shows file name followed by loc of only the latest package only lets say in a java projest 3 packages named abc, def and tyu

com.abc package having files --->abc.java
com.def package having files --->abc.java
com.tyu package having files --->FileBrowse.java ,

Comment: FileCountLine.java

the outcome shown in console is... 
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\.settings
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\bin
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com\abc
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\com\def
Directory: C:\Users\vaio\Desktop\Demo\TESTRESULT\src\tyu

Comment: FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC
*****************************************
FileBrowse.java ==> 95
FileCountLine.java ==> 53
*****************************************
SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==> 4
SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==> 296

Comment: which is not perfect. please advise HOW IT WILL SHOW FILENAME FOLLOWED BY LOC for all the files

Comment: Agarwal hope u got my point please clarify and thanks for the amazing help

Comment: Please advise as I am stuck up on this problem

Comment: Thanks a lot , waiting for positive feedback..!!

Comment: Agarwal, please update have u checked it, I am still stuck up.

Comment: Hi , I think the root cause of this problem is In the method that reads the files and the line count, we are create a NEW Map for each directory and re-assign it to the same result. Since you do not display the data before you re-assign the Map, the previous Map is no longer accessible and by the time you get to the display you only have a Map for the last directory. Instead, you should maintain a single Map and insert new values from each directory into the same Map.

Comment: just FYI, that seems to have used part of the following code:
[Java Practices - Recursive File listing][1]


  [1]: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68